# I connect an external microphone, but Ubuntu thinks I connected headphones

Tags: laptop, hp, microphone

I have an HP laptop with a single round hole for audio devices. Usually I use it for headphones, but now I need to plug in an external microphone. When I do the same with Windows, Windows asks me whether I connected a microphone or headphones, and when I can tell it that I connected a microphone, it works fine. However, Ubuntu does not ask me, and apparently it thinks that I installed headphones, since the microphone does not work: I opened the "Sound" application and saw that the system does not hear me when I speak to the external microphone - it hears me only when I speak to the internal microphone.

How can I tell Ubuntu that I installed a microphone so that it can hear me when I speak to it?